# GXT 3 change tab style (add css)

Tags: java, css, gwt, tabs, gxt

GXT 3 has a function, which adds a tab to tabpanel

```
      tabPanel.add(html, new TabItemConfig(title, true));
```

I have to change style of the name of this tab and also contents. These have no effect:

```
           tabPanel.setStyleName("tab-title", true);
           html.setStyleName("tab-title", true);
```

TabItemConfig has no method to change style.
How to achieve?...

Comment: The solution is to use appearances and styling

Answer (score 1):

I see you've found the solution, but I just leave it here, because it's quite simple and may save somebody's time:

```java
class StylableTabPanel extends TabPanel {
    public void applyTabStyles(Widget widget, String styles) {
        findItem(getWidgetIndex(widget)).applyStyles(styles);
    }
}
```

Then:

```java
tabPanel = new StylableTabPanel();
HTML shortText = new HTML("Lorem ipsum...");
tabPanel.add(shortText, "Short Text");
HTML longText = new HTML("<b>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</b>");
tabPanel.add(longText, "Long Text");
tabPanel.applyTabStyles(longText, "margin-left: 300px;");
```